# What are the Change Brush Size shortcuts in Sculpt mode using Maya Navigation?

Tags: shortcut

I'm definitely struggling for this, I use Maya Navigation, and <kbd>F</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keys are already bound.

Now in sculpt mode I can't find how to get those useful shortcuts to change dynamically size and strength of the brush, any idea how I can recover them and bind them to different shortcuts and continue using Maya Layout ?

Comment: I know size is F and scroll wheel. It also changes the strength a bit. Think of it like Focus.

Comment: As I said I'm using Maya Navigation, which use F + Shift-F already to focus to a single object or whole scene,  I cannot change that manually cause it's not present in the binding possibility. I think I must get out of Maya Navigation, see wht python command bound to F and write that down, then in Maya navigation bind those to other keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found them; the keys were bound to <kbd>B</kbd> for the size, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for the strength and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> for the rotation of the brush.

To find this, I first switched to the default layout and searched for the actions bound to <kbd>F</kbd>, noted the entries were named 'Radial Control', switched back to the Maya layout and searched for that name.